# Python IDLE and HomeBrew updated versions

Tags: python

A while ago, I downloaded Python via its website and have been using the following ever since:

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
```

It is a simple editor and I am fine with it. When I enter in command line `$ python3 --version`, I get `Python 3.5.2` obviously.

[image]

A few months ago, I installed `HomeBrew` and ever since I have been updating my Mac's Python via `$ brew update` and `$ brew upgrade`. Today, I noticed in its updating results that my latest installed and updated Python version is `python-3.6.4_4.el_capitan`

I went into my `usr/local/bin` as well as `usr/bin` and realized that there is a **variety** of versions in them. This can be seen in the two attached images:

[image]

---

[image]

I understand the one installed in `/usr/bin` is provided with my OS X and is used by the system, and other instances are provided by external packages. So, I shouldn't try to remove/uninstall `Python 2` then, **right**?

How do I clean this up and make sure **I only have the latest installed and updated Python 3.6.4 (the one managed via brew)** and also **how can I point my IDLE to this latest version**? There is no option in its menus...

Do I always have to go to http://www.python.org/download and install the latest from there? Is there anyway I can use **3.6.4** in my current IDLE? I know how to use 3.6.4 via `Terminal`, but I would like to be able to use it via my IDLE that is currently at 3.5.2

I do not have a deep knowledge of the underlying system, so when I see in other posts that somebody says change blah in the `$path` blah, I am not too sure how to do it. Of course there are many tutorials on this, but I worry following each one word by word might result in my doing something terrible to system files, etc...

So, I would appreciate someone helping me in detail and explaining to me how I can achieve the above two (in bold) so that in the process I also learn a few things and not find command line and path related subjects daunting.

Comment: As an aside: IDLE is not a great environment for developing Python code. I would recommend either getting a better editor set up (e.g. I use vim for all my Python coding), or else getting a full IDE like PyCharm.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I will go for PyCharm.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your case, I think the simplest solution is to uninstall Python from Homebrew (if you want to, you can also uninstall the 3.5 you installed using the Python.org installer), and then install Python 3.6 using the installer from the Python website.

Comment: Uninstalling Python via HomeBrew will not mess with my system Python. Correct?

Comment: Another question: How about just uninstalling the 3.5 version that I downloaded with IDLE etc... and then downloading PyCharm and using it with the latest HomeBrew Python? Is it possible to download PyCharm and get it to use the latest HomeBrew Python?

Comment: Yes, uninstalling the Homebrew Python (`/usr/local/bin/python`) will not affect the system Python (`/usr/bin/python`). And yes, you can use PyCharm with a Homebrew-installed Python, or with a Python.org-installed Python, your choice.